# Changing Values of a C-Struct in a Class for OpenGL - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have the following hard coded vertex information in my object class for use for OpenGLES 2.0 :

```
typedef struct {
float Position[3];
float Color[4];
} Vertex;

static Vertex Vertices [] = {
{{0.0, -0.0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}},
{{0.0 , 50 , 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}},
{{-50.0, 50.0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}},
{{-50.0, -0.0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1}}
};

static GLubyte Indices []= {
0, 1, 2,
2, 3, 0
};
```

What I want to do is amend this class so that I can set the vertices information when I instantiate the class. So far I have tried declaring and exposing the object in the implementation :

```
@interface StandObject : NSObject {
Vertex * Vertices;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) Vertex * Vertices;
```

And the in the .m file

```
@synthesize Vertices;
```

I then try to set the Vertices as follows, however I think the formatting here is wrong :

```
Vertices[0].Position = {0.0, -0.0, 0};
```

Can anyone offer any advice on the best way to achieve this and if I am on the right lines ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing it in this way:

```
Vertices[0].Position[0] = 0.0;
Vertices[0].Position[1] = -0.0;
Vertices[0].Position[2] = 0;
```

Maybe it's not the cleaner solution, but it will work

Comment: This gives me exc_bad_access ?

Comment: I tried the exact code I paste you and it worked for me, try removing the synthesize

Comment: Not sure that code is working as intended - it is just reading the Vertices struct from the header. No values are actually being changed.

Comment: Have you seen my code? The one from the link? In my example, the values are actually being changed

Comment: Yep - the one from the link. It takes the header Vertices as it's lead  - try changing the values in it and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Ah my mistake - I was setting the VBOs before the new values for vertices.